# Jquery code to send a mail from script editor/ content editor is giving error

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yyyyy.xxxx.org/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yyyyy.xxxx.org/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<script>

function processSendEmails() 
{

 var from = 'TestMymail@gmail.com',
        to = 'testMymail@gmail.com',
        body = 'Hello World Body',
        subject = 'Hello World Subject';

      sendEmail(from, to, body, subject);
}

function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {


  var urlTemplate = "https://yyyyy.xxxx.org" + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";

   //alert("api " + urlTemplate);

    $.ajax({
        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
        url: urlTemplate,
    crossDomain: true,  
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'},
                'From': from,'To': {'results': [to]},
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Email Sent Successfully');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', processSendEmails);

});
</script>
```

Error in sending Email:

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2130242040,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\
>
> "The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid
>   recipient.\"}}}","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}

Comment: SPUtility limitation: The recipient is limited to a valid SharePoint user for security reasons.the email recipient must be in the same domain as the SP server.

Comment: Have you tried to open the Rest API url ("http://sharepointsite/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail") in browser? Please check that.

Comment: SharePoint code can't mail to non AD users, otherwise it would be the greatest Spamming tool in the world and Microsoft shares would plummet. So put accounts in the AD, or call your own (non SharePoint) SMTP server from a proxy